# Cannot forward to Openshift app (CNAME)

Tags: dns, openshift, cname

I have a domain registered with GoDaddy, let's call it `xyz.com`

Now I add a CNAME

```
Host: openshift
Points To: myapp-mynamespace.rhcloud.com
```

When I access openshift.xyz.com I only get:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /app was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at openshift.xyz.com Port 443
```

Not sure why it tried to access /app at all, not sure if it actually did forward to Openshift app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should config Cname in Godday
2. Add alias in openshift:
   Using command line :

   rhc alias add YOUR_APP_NAME www.xyz.com

Hope it help you

Answer (score 1):

That means that you do not have the alias setup on your application correctly on OpenShift, and the server does not know what application to map that domain name to.  Make sure that you have added your custom domain to your OpenShift gear correctly.  Also, if you are using example.com and www.example.com, make sure that you added them both.  This blog post should help get you fixed up: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way

Comment: What alias should I put now?

Comment: What is your domain name?

Comment: Let say its abc.com, what alias should I put. Do you mean, let say using Godaddy for my other domain xyz.com to point its 'openshift' CNAME (i.e openshift.xyz.com) to myapp-mynamespace.rhcloud.com I have to setup domain (abc.com) in my Openshift app?